# Scan single character in c as in bash

Tags: c

I am doing program in c.
I wanted to scan my input like :

```
[root@localhost sudoers.d]# cd /home/Hitesh/
Display all 113 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Here in bash,when user enters 'n' or 'y' it directly come on prompt.

But in c program if I am taking input through getchar() and then if I press 'n' or 'y',I explicitly have to press enter key after that to resume execution.

So I want,my execution resume as soon I press 'n',it should not wait for enter key press.

How can I achieve this in c programming.

Comment: There is no standard way to achieve this, you will have to use non-standard functions. `getch()` is one such example but it is _not_ standard C and therefore not portable.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `getch ()`

Answer (score 0):

use `getch()`:

```
char answer = getch();
if(answer=='y')
   //yes!
else
   //no!
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use getch() instead of getchar().  getch() accepts only one character, so you don't want to press enter key.

```
char opt = getch();
// show typed value
printf("%c", opt );
if( opt == 'y' )
{
  ............
}
else 
{
  ............
}
```

hope this will helps

Comment: getch () is not standard library function as @lundin says,so please help if you have another option.

Comment: getch() is commonly available function in console application in windows (i don't know in linux) just include <conio.h> as header file